# How to run .net project in docker container?

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-build

I have a project written in .net, I created a dockerfile and docker-compose files with visual studio. These are my steps: **solution explorer>right click on project name> add >container Orchestrator Support**.

I try to build but I keep getting the same error. How can I solve this? Why is happening? What is the right way to open a project with docker

When I try to do `docker build .`
I got this error:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

Here my autogenerated Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

Here my autogenerated docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:
  educationwebsite:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}educationwebsite
    build:
      context: .\EducationWebSite
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be directly the answer you are looking for, but in production deployments, you should use [multi-stage](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) builds. With them, you then build your application and create dll's as output which you then use in actual application runtime image/layer.

The multi-stage Dockerfile I am using is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.6-bullseye-slim  AS base
# We create our own non root user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash appuser
# We prepare application folder and adjust RW permissions
RUN mkdir -p /app; \
    chown -R appuser:appuser /app; \
    chmod go+w /app

# Basic ENV's and setting port to listen on 8080 instead 80 (non root user cant open ports that low)
ENV TZ Europe/Ljubljana
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:8080
EXPOSE 8080

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.301-bullseye-slim AS build
ENV TZ Europe/Ljubljana
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Company.RestApiTemplate.Api/Company.RestApiTemplate.Api.csproj", "Company.RestApiTemplate.Api/"]
COPY ./nuget.config .
RUN dotnet restore "Company.RestApiTemplate.Api/Company.RestApiTemplate.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Company.RestApiTemplate.Api"
RUN dotnet build "Company.RestApiTemplate.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Company.RestApiTemplate.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
# Copy actual application dll's
COPY --chown=appuser:appuser --from=publish /app .

#Switch to application user
USER appuser
#Launch our application
CMD ["dotnet", "Company.RestApiTemplate.Api.dll"]
```

So it consists of four parts "base" part, which is base image preparation (RUNTIME), build which is actual restore and build of the dotnet project. Then we have publish which is layer for publishing the built application and finally we have final which is extension of base and we copy in the dll's and switch to app user and start the server.
Hope it helps.